# connected host has failed to respond when I run `docker run hello-world` in docker

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

The lastest version of docker(version 0.6) has been installed in my laptop (windows 10 LTSB) through the installation package `docker toolbox`. It seems to be installed correctly cause I see the logo of docker when I started the `docker quickstart terminal`. While when I run `docker run hello-world`, it returns

```
$ docker run hello-world
D:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: An error occurred trying to connect: Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.24/containers/create: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
See 'D:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

By the way, I open the vpn through `cisco anyconnect`. However, when I disconnect the vpn and run the `hello world`, it seems to just froze at

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
c04b14da8d14: Pulling fs layer
```

What happened? Can you find what's wrong with the docker or vpn?

Comment: If you Windows 10 version is supported, I recommend trying Docker for Windows instead of Toolbox: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Comment: The version in my computer is not compatiable with `docker for windows`. And I find the problem seems to be associated with VPN. Do you know how to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

You should first create a default machine (or start if already created):

```
docker-machine create default
```

Then get the environment commands for your new VM:

```
docker-machine env
```

And then connect your shell to the new machine:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

After then docker run hello-world is expected to work fine. I tested on Windows 10Pro with Docker-Toolbox